# query JSON data using slick(pg)

Tags: scala, slick

I have following JSON array stored in a column type `json` in postgresql database.

In order to write a query to "find all records where instance url is /api/mydef/definitions/3 and `rel=parent`

```
"links":[
    {
    "dsId": 2,
    "instance": "/api/mydef/definitions/3",
    "rel": "parent"
    }
  ]
```

Using [slickpg](https://github.com/tminglei/slick-pg/tree/master/core/src/main/scala/com/github/tminglei/slickpg/json) in Scala, Slick,Play environment. Trying to write a query as follow

```
 sourceInstance.filter { _.links.+>>("instance") === "/api/mydef/definitions/3" }.filter { _.links.+>>("rel") === "parent" }
```

but it's giving me postgresql error : `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: cannot extract field from a non-object`

how to query using `slickpg` extension/operators within an array and across the table to be able to get all the records matching such query criteria?

Answer (score 1):

With slick and postgresql 9.3, I am using

```
val jsonSQL=SimpleFunction.binary[Option[String],String,Option[String]]("json_extract_path_text")
```

So that this jsonSQL function can be used to extract text in the json tree. For instance a complex slick join:

```
val destTable = for {
(b,d) <- (__Ttable filter (_.xx === "foo")) 
join ( __Ltable filter (_.yy === "bar")) 
on ((a,b) => jsonSQL(a.qualifier,"JSONPATH") === b.name)
} yield (b.Id,b.d,d.id)
```